# Magento2: issue with bulk actions update - not started

Tags: magento2, attributes

After upgrade to Magento 2.4 I have issue with bulk update attributes.

```
57567f7a-e3ec-4812-a6e1-0b3861c06540    Jan 2, 2021 9:27:26 PM  Update attributes for 13898 selected products   Not Started
```

cron is running correct - because correct export products feed, running reindex etc.

I check in our second website store on M2.4 and the same issue.

Only issue with  mass update products attributes.

Has anyone encountered such a problem and do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new bug in 2.4.1 that stops bulk updates from running.

See the following issue and fix

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29797

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29814/files

in **vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/etc/db_schema.xml** change

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="operation_key" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
```

to

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="operation_key" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="true"
```

then run `bin/magento s:up`

Old jobs might well still be stuck but new jobs should complete. To clear old jobs flush the the *magento_bulk* and *magento_bulk_acknowledged* database tables.

This should be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not fix the problem for Magento 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I was able to find a proven solution that works 100% for Magento 2.4.0 and for 2.4.1
On version 2.4.2 this issue is solved.

1)

```
ALTER TABLE `magento_operation`
MODIFY COLUMN `operation_key` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Operation Key' AFTER `result_message`;
```

- update `db_schema.xml` using your favourite editor, for example:

  vim ./vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/etc/db_schema.xml +37

Change:

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="operation_key" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
```

To:

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="operation_key" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="true"
```

- Perform any necessary db updates:

  $ php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Clear out any pending messages

Since the magento_operations table wasn't updated correctly, you will need to manually update the records in the magento_operation, magento_acknowledged_bulk and magento_bulk tables.

There are a number of different ways to do that, but the following should work:

```
TRUNCATE magento_operation;
TRUNCATE magento_acknowledged_bulk;
DELETE FROM magento_bulk;
ALTER TABLE magento_bulk AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

After update `db_schema.xml` require  run trunkcate above sql query.